Google ReCaptcha V3 token not registering for iOS Simulators
We have included Google ReCaptcha V3 to Authenticate user during login flow but, ReCaptcha is not registering in iOS simulators. Can someone help us?
We are using RecaptchaEnterprise in Swift through Cocoapod and version "18.4.2", we are able to generate token in device, but not able to do so in iOS simulators and even the App got rejected from AppStore.
